Is it possible to setup mdadm raid1 on drive with running system?
Current system configuration is:
nvme1n1                   259:0    0  1.8T  0 disk  
nvme0n1                   259:1    0  1.8T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1               259:2    0  1.1G  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:3    0  1.5G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:4    0  1.8T  0 part  
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  100G  0 lvm   /

System is already booted from /. Is it possible to to create now mdadm raid1 with nvme1n1 and nvme0n1 without reinstalling entire system?

if you want to wipe your system Yes, else no as far as i know

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403691/how-can-i-create-mdadm-raid1-without-losing-data

You better have good backups.

But this makes it (nearly) offtopic in my human opinion due its not showing best practices.

Yes, it is possible. LVM is your saver.

Do have backup of important data.

Install the requirements (Ubuntu and Debian)


sudo apt install mdadm


First you need to partition nvme1n1 disk exactly same sizes as disk in use.
Efi partition should be of the same partition type;
Rest 2 partitions should be Linux RAID type.

Create pseudo RAID1 arrays on n1 disk:


sudo mdadm -C -l1 -n2 /dev/md0 /dev/nvme1n1/p2 missing
sudo mdadm -C -l1 -n2 /dev/md1 /dev/nvme1n1/p3 missing
cat /proc/mdstat


Put running md config to system

sudo /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf


Regenerate initrd with mdadm kernel module included

sudo update-initramfs -k all -u


move the LVM data volume to new md1 device (this will take a while, but is quite fast on NVME)

sudo vgextend ubuntu-vg /dev/md1
sudo pvmove /dev/nvme0n1p3
pvmove
sudo vgreduce ubuntu-vg /dev/nvme0n1p3
sudo pvremove /dev/nvme0n1p3
sudo lvs -o+devices

and check if LVM configuration is now correct, e.g. data is locate only on md1 and old nvme device is removed from VG correctly.

update grub, to make sure new config regenerated with raid support

sudo update-grub

At this point we should have data volume relocated to mdraid device md1, with system prepared for root boot on mdraid lvm device.
Now change p3 partition to type Linux RAID on original disk:
fdisk /dev/nvme0n1

In case fdisk partition type change announces that changes will be visible only after reboot, you can reboot now. And proceed further steps after reboot.
Now lets make true RAID1:
sudo mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/nvme0n1p3
cat /proc/mdstat

wait until sync is finished.
At this stage data volume should be on real raid1 device. Now you can reboot the system if not yet.
Note: /boot partition move requires little extra work, and easily can mess-up system boot, thus I will think if I will post it to separate answer later.
